# Multiple paper submission deadline extension (three times in few days)

Tags: conference, deadlines

> **Important Announcement – Paper Submission Deadline Extension**
>
> The paper submission deadline has been extended to May 25, 2015 June 1, 2015.

This is the third extension of the deadline for the meeting where I have submitted my paper.

1. To May 1, 2015 May 18, 2015.
2. To May 18, 2015 May 25, 2015.
3. And now, to May 25, 2015 June 1, 2015.

I do not know what think. I have submitted the paper on the afternoon of May 18, 2015. That evening I saw the second extension (like Cinderella, not at midnight but close).
Now I have seen another extension, and I am concerned because I have worked very hard in this project.

**The question is: there is a concrete risk that the conference could have had a few submissions and could be canceled?**

Comment: Is that indeed the deadline for an entire *conference*, or just for one of the sub-events integrated into a conference (e.g. a workshop)?

Comment: No, this is the deadline of the full-papers submission. One extension is normal, not two. Three is very strange. In the conference there is a only one deadline.

Comment: Yes, fully agree with your assessment. I only wanted the clarification because for workshops, it *can* happen and still doesn't mean the workshop cannot in any case take place at all, there is always the chance of merging workshops etc. ... for the full conference, however, I have no experience with such a situation.

Comment: One additional possible factoid you might supply: *If* the submission system uses a sequential numbering scheme, what number did your submission get (you can specify a range like "80 - 100" in case you want to protect double-blindness of your submission)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, I have seen two cases of deadline extension:

1. Some venues have a "customary" extension, which always happens, and thus all regulars know that the de facto deadline is slightly later than the initially stated deadline.
2. The other main case of extension is when a venue wants a few more submissions and is hoping an extension can drum them up.

Multiple deadline extensions sounds to me like desperation, and you might well be looking at an event that will either be cancelled or accept a lot of trash.  Unfortunately, there's not much you can do about it right other than withdraw your paper if you are nervous, which might not help you much either.

Comment: Organizers being open toward extending the deadline once if a sufficient number of authors ask for an extension (without generally and automatically extending the deadline on their own) is not another main case? I have seen several situations where deadlines where placed inconveniently in a way that they coincided with another important deadline in the same community, and thus organizers had a strong incentive to exceptionally extend their deadline once they were made aware of the issue.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper In my experience, at least, that is a rather unusual case.  Clashing deadlines like that is a) an artifact of rather poor planning by the organizers and b) something that well-organized researchers will also have dealt with in advance.  So yes, it's part of the long tail of extension reasons. It still wouldn't explain a 3x month-in-total extension like the OP reports.

Comment: Yes, I sometimes suspect I have picked subfields that essentially happen to be centered around and built upon poor planning ;) Fully agree with the unusualness of the three consecutive extensions.